# Azure Rest API usage with SAS Service

Tags: azure, rest

I am trying to use the Azure [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api) with [SAS Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas). While I got this working with the most basic GET command, I am having trouble with the setup as soon as I need to add variables to the call as they are added at the same place as the SAS token. e.g. for "List Containers" I should use the URL "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list". But the "?comp=list" part is that the same place as the SAS Token. How can I give the request both the tokens and the variables? (I do not have much experience with REST APIs, so maybe I am misunderstanding something). I also posted my code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace ConsoleProgram
{
    public class DataObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        private const string URL = "url";
        private static string urlParameters = "?token";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // List data response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters+ "&comp=list").Result;  // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
                // Parse the response body.
                var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  //Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", dataObjects);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }

            // Make any other calls using HttpClient here.

            // Dispose once all HttpClient calls are complete. This is not necessary if the containing object will be disposed of; for example in this case the HttpClient instance will be disposed automatically when the application terminates so the following call is superfluous.
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use the SAS token to call Azure blob rest API, the SAS token is used as the query string. So we can use '&' to splice SAS token and other query parameters, such as `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list&{sasToken}`.

Besides, please note that if you want to list containers in one storage account, you need to create an account SAS token.  The service SAS token cannot implement it. Regarding how to create  the account SAS token, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas)
[image]